# Table content alignment

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, multirow

I checked the questions related to this content, But i couldn't find a solution, that is helpful to me. I have issue in alignment of the table contents. I am using the multirow option and including matrices and vectors as cell elements.  I have issue only with the look. Could someone please help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{|L | c | c | c | c | c | *1{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.25\textwidth}|} c|}
\begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{1.2cm}|M{.5cm}|M{.5cm}|M{1.6cm}|M{1cm}|M{4cm}|M{1cm}|}
\hline
    Procedure & Mesh & $N_\theta$ & $N_\phi$ & D & error & Direction cosine & Time (s)\\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\multicolumn{1}{m{1.7cm}}{EN 13445-3 Max CUF}} & unique & 180 & 360 & 2.353e-5 & 1e-6 & \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -0.482 & 0.876 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.876 & -0.482 \end{bmatrix} & 17607 \\[40pt] \cline{2-8}
                                        & unique & 10 & 20 & 2.1116e-5 & 1e-6 & \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0.082 & -0.996 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -0.996 & -0.082 \end{bmatrix} & 66 \\[40pt] \cline{2-8} 
                                        & iterative & 10 & 20 & 2.1120e-5 & 1e-8 & \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -0.074 & -0.993 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -0.993 & 0.074 \end{bmatrix} & 269 \\[40pt] \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\multicolumn{1}{m{1.7cm}}{Max stress range}}   & unique & 180 & 360 & 119.893 & 1e-6 & \begin{bmatrix} 0.017 \\ -0.003 \\ 0.999 \end{bmatrix} & 2472 \\[40pt] \cline{2-8}
                                        & unique & 10 & 20 & 107.51 & 1e-6 & \begin{bmatrix} 0.323 \\ -0.111 \\ 0.94 \end{bmatrix} & 7 \\[40pt] \cline{2-8}
                                        & iterative & 10 & 20 & 119.929 & 1e-8 & \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} & 15 \\[40pt] \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{type=table}
\captionof{table}{Comparison of unique mesh and iterative mesh}
\label{ISAD_Comparison}
\centering
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please also note that `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` syntax should be replaced with `\centering` and that a `table` floating environment would probably suit your need better..

Comment: Hi.. Thank you.. I have edited like you mentioned.  But the centering option doesnt help.  I have also posted the image of the table output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things you actually don't need here; `multirow`, `multicolumn`, or even `newcolumntype`. Most of the columns can be set as centered `c` and two-row cells can be obtained with `\makecell`. The spacing around matrices can be increased by a simple trick:

`\newcommand{\pad}{^{\vphantom{\frac12}}_{\vphantom{\frac12}}}`

Also, you could use `\makegapedcells` from the `\makecell` package, but there are some incompatibilities in your case.

If you want an even better result, use `booktabs` package and the spacing around matrices will look good by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, caption, makecell}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pad}{^{\vphantom{\frac12}}_{\vphantom{\frac12}}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Procedure                      & Mesh      & $N_\theta$ & $N_\phi$ & D         & error & Direction cosine                                          & \makecell{Time\\(s)}\\\hline
                               & unique    & 180        & 360      & 2.353e-5  & 1e-6  & $\begin{bmatrix} 0                                        & -0.482                       & 0.876 \\1  & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0.876  & -0.482 \end{bmatrix}\pad$ & 17607 \\\cline{2-8}
\makecell{EN 13445-3\\Max CUF} & unique    & 10         & 20       & 2.1116e-5 & 1e-6  & $\begin{bmatrix} 0                                        & 0.082                        & -0.996 \\1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & -0.996 & -0.082 \end{bmatrix}\pad$ & 66 \\\cline{2-8}
                               & iterative & 10         & 20       & 2.1120e-5 & 1e-8  & $\begin{bmatrix} 0                                        & -0.074                       & -0.993 \\1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & -0.993 & 0.074 \end{bmatrix}\pad$  & 269 \\\hline
                               & unique    & 180        & 360      & 119.893   & 1e-6  & $\begin{bmatrix} 0.017\\-0.003 \\0.999 \end{bmatrix}\pad$ & 2472 \\\cline{2-8}
\makecell{Max stress\\range}   & unique    & 10         & 20       & 107.51    & 1e-6  & $\begin{bmatrix} 0.323\\-0.111 \\0.94 \end{bmatrix}\pad$  & 7 \\\cline{2-8}
                               & iterative & 10         & 20       & 119.929   & 1e-8  & $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix}\pad$             & 15 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{type=table}
\captionof{table}{Comparison of unique mesh and iterative mesh}
\label{ISAD_Comparison}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image]